# how get value/method automatic if user change permission from Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, android-service

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWEmm.jpg)
I am using WindowManager+WindowManger.Layout
Problem:
-example windowmanager position center move to Top.
if user turn off permission from system or PendingIntent have(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION). The windowmanger is gone but if turn on windowmanager position still top. (not complete stopService) and if I press btnShow() from class activity. its spawn double in center position.

I tried make btnStop from class Activity. its wrork but the biggest problem is how get value/method automatically is user trun off Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION from system. so class service can stop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.